# ASP.NET getting POST values from another page

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

I want to get the post values from another page, I've used this:
Request.Form["myFieldName"]

problem is after debugging, the field names, have all that "ct$100PlaceHoldermyFieldName" in it, how do I get my field value?

The form on the other page, needs all that automatic ASP.NET (I think?) As it is uses validators and client-side-validation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before but used ServerTransfer to the next page. Then you use `PreviousPage.FindControl` to get the values of the controls. Not sure if this will help your situation?

Take a look here for some more info.
http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37633.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helpful for you
Use like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"  runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

**PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"**

more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx .

to get values `Request.Form` check more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Comment: Your link doesn't explain how to get the values from form when they have the inamingcontainer string attached to it. As pointed out in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NameValueCollection to retrieve Http Posted Forms.

```
NameValueCollection collection = Request.Form;
string fieldName;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["fieldName"]))
{
  fieldName = collection["fieldName"];
}
```